# What is $nuxt property in Nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I want to know what is $nuxt property in Nuxt.js. When can you use it? And where can you use it? Can you use it in statically generated Nuxt App? Can you use it in SPA? Or is  it only for SSR mode of Nuxt.js? What are its pros and cons? I already looked in the docs and there's no elaborate explanation about it.